# What is the best way to strip out all html tags from a string?

Tags: php, html, string

Using PHP, given a string such as: `this is a <strong>string</strong>`; I need a function to strip out ALL html tags so that the output is: `this is a string`.  Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PHP has a built-in function that does exactly what you want: [`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags)

```
$text = '<b>Hello</b> World';
print strip_tags($text); // outputs Hello World
```

If you expect broken HTML, you are going to need to load it into a DOM parser and then extract the text.

Comment: +1 but be careful that strip_tags may not strip invalid HTML tags, so depending on the application you may need to do some extra processing afterwards..

Comment: strip_tags() is very bad for xss protection as it only defends against a couple of xss attack vectors.  Use htmlspecialchars($var,ENT_QUOTES)

Answer (score 5):

What about using [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags), which should do just the job ?

For instance *(quoting the doc)* :

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
```

will give you :

```
Test paragraph. Other text
```

Edit : but note that strip_tags doesn't validate what you give it. Which means that this code :

```
$text = "this is <10 a test";
var_dump(strip_tags($text));
```

Will get you :

```
string 'this is ' (length=8)
```

(Everything after the thing that looks like a starting tag gets removed).

Answer (score 1):

[`strip_tags`](http://www.php.net/strip_tags) is the function you're after. You'd use it something like this

```
$text = '<strong>Strong</strong>';
$text = strip_tags($text);
// Now $text = 'Strong'
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this to be a little more effective than [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) alone, since [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) will not zap javascript or css:

```
$search = array(
    "'<head[^>]*?>.*?</head>'si",
    "'<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>'si",
    "'<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>'si",
);
$replace = array("","",""); 
$text = strip_tags(preg_replace($search, $replace, $html));
```