# Remove HTML Formatting PHP

Tags: php

I am attempting to remove formatting from copied text off of another website.  I can use `preg_replace` along with other methods, but I want to keep `<p>`'s and such, but remove formatting such as `<font>`.

Here is what I'm using right now to clean my text currently:

`mysql_real_escape_string(str_replace("\r\n",'', $_POST['maintext']));`

Comment: http://php.net/strip_tags and observe the 2nd optional argument (allowed tags)

Comment: Consider using `array("\r", "\n")` as your first param to `str_replace()` since not all line breaks are exactly `\r\n`.

Comment: @MarcB +1 why don't you write it as an answer?

Comment: I used `strip_tags($maintext, '<p><a>');` and it still stripped the `<p>` even though it isn't supposed to.

Comment: @drummer392 You'll have to provide an example. The example in the manual is pretty clear.

Comment: Yes, I basically just copied text off of a blog on one website and pasted it into the editor on mine, performed the strip_tags, and then it gets rid of the `<p>` for some reason.

Comment: [Something that we could run ourselves](http://sscce.org/). On the order of `strip_tags("<p>my <a>string</a></p>", "<p><a>");` with clear inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Notice the notes on the article. Considering that in your example you mentioned removing <font> tags, is it possible the html has any broken tags in it, or isn't well-formed? Maybe post a link to the site that you're trying to parse so that we could try to run it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to strip out all html tags from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1256163/), [How do I remove HTML tags from a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6808181/), [Strip all HTML tags, except allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6247035/), and many, ***many*** others.

Comment: SQL quoting functions should only be used when preparing data for interpolation into an SQL statement. Moreover, interpolation shouldn't be used if prepared statements are available. The mysql extension is outdated and on its way to deprecation. New code should use mysqli or PDO, both of which support for prepared statements (as well as having other important advantages).

Comment: If the text is copyrighted, don't scrape it as it's illegal and you're opening yourself up to criminal and civil suits. It's trivial to find copyright violators.

Comment: The text I'm copying is from my friend's blog http://brockpatterson.blogspot.com